# box-shadow IE8 not working on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I've look all relevant topics but could not find solution so I created this question. 
Im trying to implement box-shadow on IE8 And its not working.. It works on IE9+?

I have simple div:

```
<span id="controls" class="box-shadow"> 
<input id="start" type="text" placeholder="Get Directions: Enter Address or Postcode"/> 
<input id="end" type="hidden" value="Text" /> 
</span>
```

And CSS:

```
#controls.box-shadow{
background-color: white;
font-size: 13px;
position: relative;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 10000;
float: right;
height: 35px;
width: 96%;
margin-left: 20px;

}
.box-shadow{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#232361')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#232361');
}
#start{ width:82%; height:27px; border:none; padding:5px}
```

Comment: Box-Shadow is a CSS3 feature and isn't supported in IE8. Not sure of any workarounds to make it work myself but maybe someone on here will know some trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box-shadow doesn't work natively in IE8 but you can use a polyfill for CSS3.

Here's a working example: http://css3pie.com/

You need to apply the polyfill to your element like so

```
.box-shadow {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #232361;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: this `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` is external file or what? :)

Comment: @EimantasBaigys yes it's an external file. A polyfill, or polyfiller, is a piece of code (or plugin) that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively.

Comment: Here's a list of many polyfill that can be used: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Hmmm, it worked on localhost, but when I updated css and uploaded files its not working anymore.... behaviour link is set correctly....

Comment: @EimantasBaigys Seems server related... can you create a .htaccess file and put it on at the root of the server? If so, simply add: "AddType text/x-component .htc" to the .htaccess file. This will tell the server to serve .htc files as a text file. For more information, read the section "Serving the correct Content-Type" on this page: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 `box-shadow` is not supported in IE8 or below. I personally would not worry about IE8 support, but if you need to, then MS has a `DropShadow` that has been around since IE5.5.

[Box Shadow Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

[Drop Shadow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx)

Comment: Link you gave I tried and I sill have same problem, and actually my css is from Drop Shadow link you provided

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any third party plugin, you can refer to this website:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/